# In 2NF, can a partial dependency have a composite primary key?

Tags: database, primary-key, database-normalization, composite-primary-key, functional-dependencies

All the examples of partial dependancy I have seen have only one attribute as a primary key.

```
A,B,C -> D,E,F
A,B-> D (composite PK)
```

Can i say "A,B->D" is a partial dependancy "A,B,C -> D,E,F" ?

Comment: This is unintelligible. (But was channeled by displayName.) PS The partial FD is {A,B,C} -> {D}. The FD moved is not the partial one; it is the one whose presence makes the other one partial.

Comment: Uppercase letters represent *sets* of attributes in [set theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/basic-set-theory.html).

Comment: Were we able to help? Can you clarify your question so we can clarify the answers?

Comment: @philipxy: No, I just meant that each uppercase letter represents a set of attributes in set theory. So the notation the OP is familiar with, JK->L, doesn't mean "the attributes JK determine the attribute L"; it means "the two sets of attributes JK determine the set of attributes L". Counting letters, as *I have seen have only one attribute as a primary key*, isn't set-oriented thinking, and it can mislead.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' OK: The two usual notations, eg JK->L with J, K, L & JK as sets (of attributes) vs eg {A,B,C}->{D,E,F} with A through F as attributes (that are set members). The quote helped. A lot of room for misunderstandings in three short sentences.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can infer, you are asking whether the decomposition can involve the new table having a composite PK, for you have so far seen only single attribute key's examples.

Yes. The idea is that if you can uniquely determine one or more non-primary attribute(s), by a part (whether a single attribute or many) of the primary key, then you should create a separate table for that.

So, if `A,B -> D`, then create another table of `{A, B, D}` and remove duplication from the bigger table.

[This link](http://rdbms.opengrass.net/2_Database%20Design/2.2_Normalisation/2.2.5_2NF-Partial%20Dependancy.html) shows the single table broken to two after removing this redundancy, though it too uses a single attribute as the key. Still, you'd get the idea by looking at the table initially and after it was divided.

Comment: Since none of the question's sentences make sensible statements about FDs, what question do you think you're answering "yes" to?

Comment: @philipxy: The title of the question.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense re FDs either. (I was including it.)

Comment: @philipxy: Please see the link in the last paragraph and the paragraph itself. The link shows a 2NF qualification for a table. As much as I could infer, the OP is asking whether the decomposition can involve the new table having a composite PK, for (s)he has so far seen only single attribute key's examples.

Comment: Wow. Usually when I can't figure out what someone means, nobody can.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Your title question is ill-formed re FDs, and your first sentence is ill-formed re FDs, and what you ask about saying is ill-formed re FDs. (Please rephrase your question to make sense re FDs by using terminology properly. Please make the connections between your sentences clear and explain your examples.)

---

We say that a FD (functional dependency) X -> Y holds or that Y is functionally dependent on X or that X functionally determines Y or that Y is functionally determined by X. We often leave the "functionally" out. We say that X -> Y is partial when some smaller/proper subset of X also determines Y. The terminology "partial" arises because Y is dependent on only *part* of X. A FD that is not partial is full. Notice that CKs (candidate keys) are not involved.

> ```
> A,B,C -> D,E,F
> A,B-> D (composite PK)
> ```

Normalization involves CKs. The only way that it involves PKs (primary keys) is that there is a tradition irrelevant to normalization to pick one CK to call "the PK". Of course, if there's only one CK then it's the only choice for PK and we can call it the PK.

I'll assume that A-F are the only attributes of some relation value or variable. If these two FDs (and those in their closure and no others) hold, then {A,B} is *not* a CK. {A,B,C} is the only CK.

> Can i say "A,B->D" is a partial dependancy "A,B,C -> D,E,F" ?

It's never the case that an FD "is" a different FD. Maybe you mean "is a partial FD *of*". But it doesn't make sense to say that a FD "is a partial FD of" some FD. I don't know whether your "Can I can say" means "Is it true that" or "Does it make sense to say". But it doesn't make sense to say that. I don't know what you are trying to ask.

But here are some things that are true:

{A,B,C} -> {D,E,F} is not partial because no smaller/proper subset of {A,B,C} determines {D,E,F}. {A,B} -> {D} is not partial because no smaller/proper subset of {A,B} determines {D}. But {A,B,C} -> {D} is partial because smaller/proper subset {A,B} of {A,B,C} determines {D}.

A relation is in 2NF when no non-prime attribute is partially dependent on a CK. Ie when all non-prime attributes are fully functionally dependent on every CK. Since non-prime attribute {D} is partially dependent on CK {A,B,C}, this relation  value or variable is not in 2NF.

> In 2NF, can a partial dependency have a composite primary key?

This is also doesn't make sense. A partial FD doesn't "have" a PK or CK. I don't know what you are trying to ask. Maybe you mean "determinant" not "PK".

> All the examples of partial dependancy I have seen have only one attribute as a primary key.

This also doesn't make sense since dependencies don't "have" PKs or CKs. Maybe you are trying to say, all the examples of partial FDs you have seen are in relations that have only one attribute as a CK. Maybe you are trying to say that all the examples of partial FDs you have seen have only one attribute as a *determinant*.

The only time that a partial FD can have a single-attribute *determinant* is when {} is its subset determinant. Ie if {J} -> Y is partial then {} -> Y. This is when the Y subrow value is the same in every tuple. So you have probably *never thought about* a partial dependency *not* having a composite determinant. (So you probably *didn't* mean "determinant" for "PK".)

(I also can't connect any these three quotes to each other or your examples.)